# How to let full-screen be on specific monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, compiz, fullscreen

I have two displays, they're arranged as:

```
         +----------+
         |          |
+--------+    B     |
|   A    |          |
+--------+----------+
```

With an application, say Adobe Reader, I can move the window to display A, or display B, or half by half. I can maximize it, too, on whatever display I like.

However, when I switch it to full-screen mode. it always occupies the display A, I can't move it to display B, though.

Is it possible to make it on display B? I'm not going to re-arrange the monitors to make display A at the right side.

I'm using Ubuntu Maverick, with the Compiz window manager.

Comment: Generally applications default to the 'main monitor' for full screen. With most there isn't a way around this.

Comment: I'm gonna make the bold assumption that your problem lies with wine-based applications (e.g. Adobe Reader). 

One solution is to create a window for wine that covers the exact resolution of display B.

First run winecfg, next select 'Graphics' tab, following which, tick ‘emulate a virtual desktop’ and enter the resolution of Display B.

Now you can move this window to cover Display B and fullscreen the operation within the window. The only small issue is a small buffer region made by the border of the window.

Comment: Oh, my god, it's a Wine application. You are right, it's all about wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna make the bold assumption that your problem lies with wine-based applications (e.g. Adobe Reader). One solution is to create a window for wine that covers the exact resolution of display B. First run winecfg, next select 'Graphics' tab, following which, tick ‘emulate a virtual desktop’ and enter the resolution of Display B. Now you can move this window to cover Display B and fullscreen the operation within the window. The only small issue is a small buffer region made by the border of the window.