# How to choose which display to run a fullscreen program in windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, fullscreen, unity3d

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/256090/how-to-let-full-screen-be-on-specific-monitor), but for windows. Particularly with a unity game that needs to be run on a second "extended" monitor in full-screen mode. I saw someone use a cmd prompt and specify which display to send it to (0 or 1), but I never got the chance to save the command, and I haven't had any luck searching for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is any way to do this using the built in Windows tools. There are several 3rd party apps which do allow for this. One I might try is [Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/) but I say that mainly because it is OSS. [UltraMon](http://realtimesoft.com/ultramon/overview/) is the actual tool I use for this but it is commercial AFAIK.

Comment: I was sure I saw some sort of CMD command that invoked the .exe and specified which display to run it on (it may have been some sort of direct X or graphics parameter, and it may be unity specific), but I am pretty sure something along those lines exists..

Comment: I figured it out - holding ctrl down while unity is starting will open up a CMD window with additional options.